# Excel VBA: Why does event trigger twice?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to avoid Event loops by disabling Events at crucial points. However, it doesn't always work. For instance, this code for a Combo box:

```
Private Sub TempComboS_Change()
Dim e
e = Application.EnableEvents
Application.EnableEvents = False
  ' 
Application.EnableEvents = e
End Sub
```

The blank line is where the useful code goes; as it stands it obviously doesn't do anything. However, when I run it this way (with the blank line), it reaches "End Sub", then it goes back to the beginning and runs again.  (This would make the useful code run twice).

Why is this happening?

EDIT: To clarify for the folks who've been helping me.

I have a macro that opens the dropdown list of the Combo box, activates it, then ends. It works properly. When I select an item from the open list, the Change event runs. This is the current version of the change event:

```
Private Sub TempComboS_Change()
End Sub
```

I put a breakpoint on the Private Sub line. It shows that this Change event runs, then runs again. I suspect that it has been doing this all along, and I noticed it now because I need to add code here.

I have no class modules or userforms. The controls are on a worksheet.

I'm going to try the "Run Once" suggestion, and I'll let you know if it works.

---

I tried the "Run Once" code you suggested. It *sort* of works, but I seem to have a bigger issue. When I select a drop-down list from a data-validated cell, the TempComboS_Change event triggers -- but not only didn't I touch this combo box, the cell isn't the LinkedCell for the combo box. In other words, it seems to be triggering by actions **unconnected** to the combo box!

Got to find out about that Call Stack thing...

Comment: Try removing `Dim e
e = Application.EnableEvents` and replace `Application.EnableEvents = e` with `Application.EnableEvents = True`. Re-run the code. Does it still run twice?

Comment: If it truly hits `End Sub` then your `TempComboS_Change()` is being called twice from another part of your code.  Debug and step through your calling code. Should be able to tell where the second call is coming from.  You can also verify this by removing all code from this sub and just put a `msgbox` in to see if it gets called twice.

Comment: BK201: Yes, it still runs twice.

Comment: In fact, if I stop the execution partway through, it immediately starts again. <br/>Portland: There is no calling code. For this test I've been running it either by changing the Combo box, or by running the procedure in the IDE window.<br/>Here's something else weird: I inserted a line "TempComboS.Visible = False" to hide the combo box, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Regardless of why it is firing twice, Application.EnableEvents does not apply to userform controls.

Comment: Do you have any other event code in your userform? Or any custom classes?

Comment: I'm not using a userform; the controls are on a worksheet. I have no custom classes.

Comment: Did you check the Call stack during the second firing?

Comment: No. Can you explain to me how to do that?

Comment: Okay, I found the Code Stack window. In most cases the only entry is the procedure I'm currently in. Other times, when there is a list of calls, there are entries that say "[<Non-Basic Code>]". What can I do to get more info on that?

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson: Not sure if it helps here, but look into `Application.Caller`- this might give you a hint what's triggering the event. PS: Please use the @notation to reply to individual comments, so people get notified! :-)

Comment: Sorry Shawn, I didn't see your response before (no @tag to me). Great! You found the Call Stack window in VBE. My suggestion was to set a break point at the first event then use F8 to step through the code and check the call stack when it fires the second time.  If you play around with that you will probably see some pattern regarding the non-basic code. I don't know how to trace exactly what that is...  I would have to infer (guess), same as you...

Comment: If that doesn't help then I use a little system that I created for investigating these things.  I will insert the code in an answer below...

Comment: @PeterAlbert I tried this:

Comment: @PeterAlbert I tried the Application.Caller code from this MS website [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193687.aspx). So far, when the event triggers **properly**, the Application Caller returns "Error". Any idea why?

Comment: @CoolBlue I've always wanted code like this, thanks. Will it help capture events triggered by a data validation drop-down that's not supposed to trigger any events?

Comment: @CoolBlue Okay, I've tried it. It seems to confirm that a dropdown list on Sheet "U" will sometimes trigger a combobox Change event, then a Click event, on Sheet "S". Sometimes.

Comment: Sorry, then Application.Caller is not helpful here - depending on the trigger it sometimes contains relevant information, but seems not in your case. :-/

Comment: I thought @PeterAlbert had found an undocumented feature because the MSDN help is very clear that Application.Caller will in fact return an error in this instance.

Comment: @ShawnVWilson the code I provided is just to reveal what's going on. Unfortunately it can't tell you why so technically, it's not really an answer. Are you able to post an example workbook?

Comment: @CoolBlue I'm not sure I have permission. I'll have to let you know tommorrow.  Since this has drifted from my original question, should I start a new post?  The new question would be "Why are Data Validation lists, and lines of code unrelated to combo boxes, triggering the Change and Click events of the combo boxes?" Someone else who tried to help me said that even code in other workbooks are triggering these events!

Comment: Here's something interesting: I found a post on ExcelForum of someone who had a similar problem. His problem was caused by INDEX functions, VLookups, and ComboBoxes with linked cells. I'm using ALL of that too.  Let's see if I can stay awake long enough to try the fix.

Comment: I think the problem and therefore the question is still the same, but as you learn more, the question topic becomes more specific... I think you should just edit the title and the content based on what you learn to further focus the question. Just my opinion :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit of code to help investigate "sequence of events" issues

In a Standard Module

```
Public Enum eNewLine
    No
    Before
    After
    Both
End Enum

Public Function timeStamp(Optional d As Double = 0, Optional newLine As eNewLine = No, Optional Indent As Long = 0, _
                            Optional Caller As String, Optional Context As String, Optional message As String) As String
Dim errorMessage As String

    If Err.number <> 0 Then
        errorMessage = "ERROR: " & Err.number & ": " & Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    End If
    If d = 0 Then d = Time
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        timeStamp = .Text(Hour(d), "00") & ":" & .Text(Minute(d), "00") & ":" & .Text(Second(d), "00") & ":" & .rept(Chr(9), Indent)
    End With
    If Len(Caller) <> 0 Then timeStamp = timeStamp & Chr(9) & Caller
    If Len(Context) <> 0 Then timeStamp = timeStamp & ": " & Chr(9) & Context
    If Len(message) <> 0 Then timeStamp = timeStamp & ": " & Chr(9) & message
    Select Case newLine
    Case Before
        timeStamp = Chr(10) & timeStamp
    Case After
        timeStamp = timeStamp & Chr(10)
    Case Both
        timeStamp = Chr(10) & timeStamp & Chr(10)
    Case Else
    End Select
    If Len(errorMessage) <> 0 Then
        timeStamp = timeStamp & Chr(9) & errorMessage
    End If

End Function
```

At the top of each Module

```
'Module level Trace Hearder
Const debugEvents as Boolean = True
Const cModuleName As String = "myModuleName"
Const cModuleIndent As Long = 1
```

You can assign a module level indent for each module to organise the hierarchy an make it easy to understand.

In each Sub or Function (or property if you need)...

```
sub mySubName()
Const cMyName As String = "mySubName"

If debugEvents Then Debug.Print timeStamp(NewLine:=Before,Indent:=cModuleIndent, Caller:=cModuleName, Context:=cMyName, Message:="Start")

'Do stuff

If debugEvents Then Debug.Print timeStamp(NewLine:=After,Indent:=cModuleIndent, Caller:=cModuleName, Context:=cMyName, Message:="End")
End Sub
```

...Or you can use Me.Name for the Context if its a form or a sheet etc. and you can put whatever message or variable values you like in the Message.

You can also use a Timer (eg MicroTimer) and put the result in the Message section.

Here is an example output:

```
15:54:07:       Roll-Up Select:     Worksheet_Activate:      Start: 3.24591834214516E-03


15:54:07:           cDataViewSheet:     Class_Initialize:   Start

15:54:07:               cRevealTarget:  Class_Initialize:   START
15:54:07:               cRevealTarget:  Class_Initialize:   END

15:54:09:           cDataViewSheet:     startTimer:     : START
15:54:09:           cDataViewSheet:     startTimer:     init Timer
15:54:09:               cOnTime:    Class_Initialize
15:54:09:               cOnTime:    Let PulseTime:  Inheret PulseTime from host sheet
15:54:09:           cDataViewSheet:     startTimer:     : END

15:54:09:       Roll-Up Select:     Worksheet_Activate:      END:   1.38736216780671
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub cmbOrder_Change()
    If cmbOrder = "" Then Exit Sub

    Dim arr As Variant, maxorder As Integer
    arr = Range("rngOrder")
    maxorder = WorksheetFunction.Max(arr)
    Dim errmsg As String, err As Boolean
    err = False
    errmsg = "This value must be a whole number between 1 and " & maxorder + 1
    Dim v As Variant
    v = cmbOrder.Value
    If IsNumeric(v) = False Or (IsNumeric(v) = True And (v > maxorder + 1) Or v < 1) 
    Then
        MsgBox errmsg
        cmbOrder = ""
        err = False
    Else
        txtOrder.Value = cmbOrder.Value
    End If

End Sub
```

A bit late to the party but the problem of code repetition can be shown here in similar circumstances. Remove the first line of code and any error messages are dished out twice. This is because of the line that clears the ComboBox that is regarded as a change and picks up another error as null input is an error! May help someone with similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Combobox_Change() will fire whenever there is a change in the combobox. For example

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.AddItem "Bah Blah"
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    '~~> If something is selected in the combo then
    '~~> this line will cause ComboBox1_Change to fire
    ComboBox1.Clear
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    MsgBox "A"
End Sub
```

So if you load the userform and select an item `ComboBox1_Change` will fire. You then use the commanbutton to clear the combo the `ComboBox1_Change` will again fire.

There is one more scenario when the change will again fire. When you `change` the combobox from the `ComboBox1_Change` event itself. Here is an example. And I `believe` this is what is happening in your case.

**Scenario 1**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.AddItem "Bah Blah"
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    MsgBox "A"
    ComboBox1.Clear
End Sub
```

**Scenario 2**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.AddItem "Bah Blah"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "Bah Blah Blah"
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    MsgBox "A"
    ComboBox1.ListIndex = 1
End Sub
```

In the first scenario you can getaway with

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.AddItem "Bah Blah"
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If ComboBox1 <> "" Then
        MsgBox "A"
    End If
End Sub
```

In the 2nd Scenario, you can use something like this

```
Dim boolRunOnce As Boolean

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.AddItem "Bah Blah"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "Bah Blah Blah"
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If boolRunOnce = False Then
        MsgBox "A"
        boolRunOnce = True
        ComboBox1.ListIndex = 1
    Else
        boolRunOnce = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: As you can see in my code snippet, there is no code in the change event that affects the combo box. In fact, it's running twice when there is no code in the Change event at all.

Comment: I would like to see your workbook if possible? If yes, then can you upload the same in www.wikisend.com and share the link here?

Comment: I'm not sure I can get permission to send the whole workbook. I don't suppose there's something in particular I can show you?

Comment: You can improve this code by using the Static keyword to declare the boolRunOnce inside the sub (if you're certain this code will always trigger twice)